# Exactness of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ be an arbitrary continuously differentiable function. If the ordinary differential equation $$(3y^2-x)f(x+y^2)+2y(y^2-3x)f(x+y^2)y'=0$$

is exact. Then which of the following are true

1) $xf'(x)-3f(x)=0$

2)  $xf'(x)+3f(x)=0$

3) $f'(x)+3f(x)=0$

4)  $f'(x)-3f(x)=0$

I tried using $Mdx+Ndy=0$, but I did not get any option. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The second option seems correct to me ..

I used f for $f(y^2+x)$ for simplicity except in the last line

$$(3y^2-x)f(x+y^2)dx+2y(y^2-3x)f(x+y^2)dy=0$$

$$Pdx+Qdy=0$$

$$\partial_y P= f\times 6y+2yf' \times (3y^2-x)$$
$$\partial_x Q= f\times (-6y)+f' \times 2y(y^2-3x)$$
Equate both expressions for exactness
$$\partial_y P=\partial_x Q$$

$$ f\times 6y+2yf' \times (3y^2-x)- f\times (-6y)-f' \times 2y(y^2-3x)=0$$
$$12yf+4y(y^2+x)f'=0$$
$$(y^2+x)f'=-3f$$
$$(y^2+x)f'(y^2+x)=-3f(y^2+x) \implies xf'(x)=-3f(x)$$